Updating many records at once in MongoDb using Mulesoft
I wanted to update many records at mongoDb using mulesoft and this connector:
<mongo:update-documents

I didn't find any examples where somebody updatedmany records at once but i can see that there are options for that:

I tried using this connector:
<mongo:update-documents collectionName="Launches" doc:name="Update documents" doc:id="0987116b-5b7a-4d1f-894e-fd61c6dcaf91" config-ref="MongoDB_Launches_Config" multipleUpdate="true" upsert="true">
    <mongo:query><![CDATA[#["updateMany": payload]]]></mongo:query>
</mongo:update-documents>

for this payload:
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e4224b"
    },
    "update": {
      "set": {
        "rocket": {
          "name": "Falcon 1"
        },
        "success": false,
        "details": "Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle",
        "name": "FalconSat",
        "date_utc": "2006-03-24T22:30:00.000Z",
        "id": "5eb87cd9ffd86e000604b32a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e4224d"
    },
    "update": {
      "set": {
        "rocket": {
          "name": "Falcon 1"
        },
        "success": false,
        "details": "Residual stage 1 thrust led to collision between stage 1 and stage 2",
        "name": "Trailblazer",
        "date_utc": "2008-08-03T03:34:00.000Z",
        "id": "5eb87cdbffd86e000604b32c"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "667ddca427b8b54816e42251"
    },
    "update": {
      "set": {
        "rocket": {
          "name": "Falcon 9"
        },
        "success": true,
        "details": null,
        "name": "COTS 1",
        "date_utc": "2010-12-08T15:43:00.000Z",
        "id": "5eb87cdeffd86e000604b330"
      }
    }
  }


But got this error: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.
I tried some other payloads but it didn't work either and worst of all i dont see any guides regarding this topic.

What is the connector version are you using?
